# Double content in Blocks (Magento 2.3.5-p2)

Tags: blocks

When I add single image in blocks I end up with doubled images on the storefront:

https://military1st.gyazo.com/fe7d99b60680dbc2375734762dd07fc0

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check by doing caching and indexing? HAve you try compilation one's?

Comment: The cache is cleared to the same effect.

Compilation as in placing images in columns? Tried that, the same effect.

Comment: Magento compilation command I am talking about. try to run that command one's.

Comment: No idea what's Magento compilation command.